# Large ram consumption and occasional freezing in android app

Tags: android, memory

So my app is taking up 80MB or RAM and occasionally when switching between activities, the screen goes black and it takes over a minute for the proper content to appear. All it does is load listviews in each activity. I made sure to execute all my AsyncTasks in the loading screen when the activity is first started, and I then use shared preferences to store the data and use it across all activities so that I don't have to execute a new Asynctask each time an activity is started. This is why I am puzzled as to why this happens. The only thing I can think of is that the activities don't get killed when I call `finish()` as this usually occurs when I switch between activities many times.

Sample Activity:

```html
public class AllGameslistActivity extends Activity {
    private Bet newBet = new Bet();
    private double stake = 0.00;
    private String name = "";
    private double newwinnings;
    private ArrayList<TipDisplayer> alltips = new ArrayList<>();
    private String newwinningstoString;
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private String selection;
    private ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<BetParameters> listwriter = new ArrayList<>();

    // Progress Dialog
    private static String url_all_games = "****";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gamesList;

    // url to get all products list

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_GAMELIST = "gamelist";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_LEAGUE = "League";
    private static final String TAG_TEAMS = "Teams";
    private static final String TAG_BET = "Bet";
    private static final String TAG_ODDS = "Odds";
    private static final String TAG_DATETIMER = "DateTimer";
    private static final String TAG_COMMENTS = "Comments";
    private static final String TAG_TYPE = "Type";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray allgames = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_bets);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_out, R.anim.push_up_in);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);



        menu menu =  (menu) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
        menu.betnowclick();
        SessionManager session;
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        name = user.get(SessionManager.USERNAME);
        menu.updateinfo(getName());
        alltips = session.getalltips();
        PopulateList();

        // Hashmap for ListView
        gamesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        //new LoadAllGames().execute();

        // Get listview



    }

    private void PopulateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter(alltips);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllGames extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_games, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Games: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Games
                    allgames = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GAMELIST);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < allgames.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = allgames.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String league = c.getString(TAG_LEAGUE);
                        String odds = c.getString(TAG_ODDS);
                        String comments = c.getString(TAG_COMMENTS);
                        String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                        String bet = c.getString(TAG_BET);
                        String datetimer = c.getString(TAG_DATETIMER);
                        String Teams = c.getString(TAG_TEAMS);
                        Double Odds = Double.parseDouble(odds);



                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_LEAGUE,league);
                        map.put(TAG_ODDS,odds);
                        map.put(TAG_COMMENTS,comments);
                        map.put(TAG_TYPE,type);
                        map.put(TAG_BET,bet);
                        map.put(TAG_DATETIMER,datetimer);
                        map.put(TAG_TEAMS, Teams);
                        Log.d("id", id);
                        Log.d("league", league);
                        Log.d("odds", odds);
                        Log.d("comments", comments);
                        Log.d("Type", type);
                        Log.d("bet", bet);
                        Log.d("datetimer", datetimer);
                        Log.d("teams",Teams);

                        alltips.add(i, new TipDisplayer(id, league, Teams, bet, odds, datetimer, comments, type));

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        gamesList.add(map);
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            // updating UI from Background Thread
        PopulateList();


        }


    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView leaguetxt;
        TextView datetxt;
        TextView teamstxt;
        TextView bettxt;
        TextView betid;
        TextView typetxt;
        TextView commentstxt;
        Button oddsbtn;
        LinearLayout item;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            leaguetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.leaguetxt);
            datetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.datetxt);
            teamstxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
            bettxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
            betid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gid);
            typetxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.difficultytxt);
            commentstxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.commenttxt);
            oddsbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
            item = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
        }
    }
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TipDisplayer> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(AllGameslistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, alltips);

        }
        public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<TipDisplayer> alltips) {
            super(AllGameslistActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, alltips);
            alltips = alltips;  // declare tomee in the Adapter, don't use static

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             View itemView = convertView;
            TipDisplayer currentwriter = alltips.get(position);
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
                itemView.setTag(holder);
                Log.d("SETTING","new holder");

            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
                Log.d("plzwork",ids.toString());
                if (!ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(holder.betid.getText().toString()))) {
                    Log.d("doesn't contain", "doesn't contain");
                    Log.d("betid",holder.betid.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("bettxt", holder.bettxt.getText().toString());
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("recycling contains", "contains");
                    Log.d("betid", holder.betid.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("bettxt", holder.bettxt.getText().toString());
                }
                Log.d("Recycling","recycling");

            }
            holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
                    Button b = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
                    ListView listView = (ListView) layout.getParent();
                    final int position = listView.getPositionForView(listView);
                    String buttontext = b.getText().toString();
                    Button lastchance = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
                    TextView betidtextbox = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gid);
                    String betid = betidtextbox.getText().toString();
                    TipDisplayer currentwriter = alltips.get(position + 1);
                    Log.d("plzworkkkk", newBet.toString());
                    if (ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(betid))) {
                        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                        b.setTextSize(18);
                        ids.remove(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(betid)));
                        Log.d("plzworkkkkkkk", newBet.toString());
                        currentwriter.toggleHighlighted();
                        //checkhighlight(layout);
                        Log.d("getodds", buttontext);
                        selection = "home";

                        TextView teamss = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
                        String teams = teamss.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("teams", teams);
                        TextView bet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
                        String bettxt = bet.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("btxttext", bettxt);
                        newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, false, teams, selection, bettxt);
                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                        if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            stake = 0.00;
                            newwinnings = 0.00;
                            potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");

                        } else {
                            mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                              int count, int after) {
                                }

                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                          int before, int count) {
                                    if (s.length() != 0) {
                                        stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                                    } else {
                                        stake = 0.00;
                                        newwinnings = 0.00;
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();

                                    }
                                }

                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                }
                            });
                            //stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
                            newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                            potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                            newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


                        }
                    } else {

                        ids.add(Integer.parseInt(betid));
                        //checkhighlight(layout);

                        b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB102E"));
                        b.setTextSize(20);
                        currentwriter.toggleHighlighted();
                        selection = "home";
                        String getodds = lastchance.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("getoddsss", getodds);
                        EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                        if (mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            stake = 0.00;
                            newwinnings = 0.00;
                            TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                            potentialWinnings.setText("0.00");
                        } else {
                            mEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                              int count, int after) {
                                }

                                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                          int before, int count) {
                                    if (s.length() != 0) {
                                        stake = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                                    } else {
                                        stake = 0.00;
                                        double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                                        newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                                        TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                                        TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                                        myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                                        potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                                        newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();
                                    }
                                }

                                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                }
                            });
                            stake = Double.parseDouble(mEdit.getText().toString());
                            TextView teamms = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.teamstxt);
                            String teams = teamms.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("teams", teams);
                            TextView bet = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bettxt);
                            String bettxt = (String) bet.getText().toString();
                            Log.d("bettxt", bettxt);
                            newBet.generateoddstesting(betid, buttontext, true, teams, selection, bettxt);
                            double newodds = newBet.calculateodds();
                            newwinnings = stake * newodds;
                            TextView myBetOdds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bettingodds);
                            TextView potentialWinnings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potentialwinnings);
                            myBetOdds.setText("@" + String.format("%.2f", newodds) + "/1");
                            potentialWinnings.setText(String.format("%.2f", (newwinnings)));
                            newwinningstoString = potentialWinnings.getText().toString();


                        }
                    }

                }
            });





            String leaguetext = currentwriter.getLeague();
            String datetext = currentwriter.getDatetimer();
            String teamstext = currentwriter.getTeams();
            String bettext = currentwriter.getBet();
            String typetext = currentwriter.getType();
            String idtext = currentwriter.getId();
            String commentsText = currentwriter.getComments();
            String oddstext = currentwriter.getOdds();
            holder.leaguetxt.setText(leaguetext);
            holder.datetxt.setText(datetext.substring(0,datetext.lastIndexOf(":")) + " GMT");
            holder.teamstxt.setText(teamstext);
            holder.bettxt.setText(bettext);
            holder.betid.setText(idtext);
            holder.commentstxt.setText(commentsText);
            holder.oddsbtn.setText(oddstext);
            holder.typetxt.setText(typetext);
            if (typetext.equals("Low Risk")) {
                holder.typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#067103"));
            }
            else if (typetext.equals("Medium Risk")) {
                holder.typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D9D216"));
            }
            else if (typetext.equals("Longshot")) {
                holder.typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F75528"));
            }


            return itemView;


        }
        @Override

        public int getViewTypeCount() {

            return getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            return position;
        }

    }





    public void clicking(View v) {

}

public void NewBetMaker(View v) {
    menu menu =  (menu) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    int value = (int) stake;
    if (value == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter Stake");
        builder.setMessage("You did not enter any stake for your bet.");

        builder.setNeutralButton("Ok.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm Bet Placement");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you would like to place this bet?");

        builder.setNegativeButton("Nope.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES, BET NOW!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog
                menu menu =  (menu) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
                int pass = (int) stake;
                Intent i = new Intent(AllGameslistActivity.this, MyBets.class);

                HashMap<Integer, Game> listofgames = new HashMap<Integer, Game>();
                HashMap<Integer,String> betdatabasesetter = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                listofgames = newBet.getlistofgames();
                for (Integer x : listofgames.keySet()) {
                    TextView teams = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    String getTeams = listofgames.get(x).getTeams();
                    teams.setText(getTeams);
                    TextView selectionodds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                    String selectedoutcome = listofgames.get(x).getSelection();
                    Double selectedoutcomeodds = listofgames.get(x).getSelectedOdds();
                    String selectedteam = "";
                    if (selectedoutcome.equals("home")) {
                        selectedteam = listofgames.get(x).getBet();
                        betdatabasesetter.put(x,"1");
                    }
                    String selection = (selectedteam + " @" + selectedoutcomeodds);
                    BetParameters y = new BetParameters(getTeams, selection);
                    listwriter.add(y);
                    Log.d("teams", getTeams);
                    Log.d("selected odds", Double.toString(selectedoutcomeodds));
                    Log.d("selected team", selectedteam);
                    Log.d("selected outcome", selectedoutcome);
                    Log.d("selection", selection);


                }
                i.putExtra("hash",new DataWrapper(betdatabasesetter));
                i.putExtra("data", new DataWrapper(listwriter));
                i.putExtra("stake", stake);
                i.putExtra("winnings",newwinningstoString);
                ((AppController) getApplicationContext()).setGamesList(gamesList);

                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }




        });



        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }



}
public String getName() {
    SessionManager session;
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    name = user.get(SessionManager.USERNAME);
    return name;
}

    public void checkhighlight(View v) {
        TextView betid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gid);
        String id = betid.getText().toString();
        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.oddsbutton);
        if (ids.contains(Integer.parseInt(id))) {
                button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EB102E"));
                button.setTextSize(20);
        }
        else {
            button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            button.setTextSize(18);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems to be a memory leak! How big are your list views in terms of items?

Comment: Code really helps with debugging the issue

Comment: It sounds like you are doing some long process on the UI thread when loading the activity. Without code I can only guess.

Comment: The app has several activities, I don't think posting all of them makes sense. @dharms I execute several asynctasks one after the other with one being called in the onpostexecute of the previous one. This doesn't seem to be the problem, loading takes a few seconds, but the problem occurs later on in the app when I'm switching between the activities when all the data is already loaded and the only computation should be populating the listviews. At the moment, they're not long at all, around 5-6 items. I also use a `viewholder` to increase the efficiency

Comment: I also have a lot of `Log` calls for debugging, by a lot I mean around 100. I don't know if this can be an issue

Comment: How are you storing the data? Are you parsing it again when you load the activity? Just because you get the data earlier doesn't mean you are still not running a long process in the `onCreate` or `onResume` of an activity. It could also be completely unrelated to the data.

Comment: I store the data in an array in sharedpreferences. I then populate the listview from the array using a custom adapter

Comment: I can post some code if you want from one of the activities or something, is there any specific kind of code you're interested in (like asynctasks) or should I post the whole activity?